# Getting the creator of a file in a shared drive in Google Drive API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I need to count the files created by the requesting user in a shared drive. I understand that there is no real ownership concept for files in shared drives. But when viewing the details of a file on the Drive Webapp it shows a field named "Creator", even in shared drives. So this information must be stored anywhere. It is possible to query it somehow through the Drive API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no method to return the creator in Google Drive API at the moment.

This is a product limitation for Google Drive API, this request can be promoted for future development through [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/support#missing_features).

As an alternative, you can get the creator of a Shared Drive by using the Google Drive audits from the Reports API https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive#create, however, data retention time for reports is 6 months.